# How to change Macro to delete the " list of column name" from delete all but list of names

Tags: excel, vba

How to change Macro so that it deletes the list of columns, as it works now it deletes everything not in the column.

I have tried but could not get it.

Thanks

```
Sub DeleteColumns()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ColList As String, ColArray() As String
Dim LastCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim boolFound As Boolean
Dim delCols As Range

On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'~~> Set your sheet here
Set ws = Sheets("360")

'~~> List of columns you want to keep. You can keep adding or deleting from this.
'~~> Just ensure that the column names are separated by a COMMA
'~~> The names below can be in any case. It doesn't matter
ColList = "{TOKEN:ATTRIBUTE_3}, {TOKEN:ATTRIBUTE_4}"

'~~> Create an array for comparision
ColArray = Split(ColList, ",")

'~~> Get the last column
LastCol = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Column

'~~> Loop through the Cols. Since there are only 100 Columns
'~~> I am not using .Find and .FindNext
'~~> If you are interested in learning how .Find and .Findnext
'~~> works then see this link
'~~> http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/
For i = 1 To LastCol
    boolFound = False
    '~~> Checking of the current cell value is present in the array
    For j = LBound(ColArray) To UBound(ColArray)
        If UCase(Trim(ws.Cells(1, i).Value)) = UCase(Trim(ColArray(j))) Then
            '~~> Match Found
            boolFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
   '~~> If not match not found
    If boolFound = False Then
        If delCols Is Nothing Then
            Set delCols = ws.Columns(i)
        Else
            Set delCols = Union(delCols, ws.Columns(i))
        End If
    End If
Next i

'~~> Act on columns
If Not delCols Is Nothing Then delCols.Delete

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just change this line

```
If boolFound = False Then
```

To check for True instead?

```
If boolFound = True Then
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion but did not work.

Comment: "did not work" doesn't tell us anything.  What do you mean?  The original code looks for any column that **is not** part of the ColArray.  It checks for that by using the boolFound variable, and then looking to see if boolFound is False.  By changing that to check if boolFound is true, it will instead look for columns that **are** part of ColArray.

Comment: Sorry about my lack of articulation and clarity.  I Deleted my macro then added it again and made your changes, this time it worked as hoped, somewhere in my attempts to find out how to alter the code I introduced a error. Thank you for your assistance.